# Find all changes to single line with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revision-history, blame

I can use Log to find the full history of a single file, and I can use Blame to find who last changed a single line.

Is there a way to get the full history of a single line with TortoisSVN or its console counterpart?

---

***Reason:** I need to find out when a certain line in a file with lots of changes got broken, and the last change was not what broke it...*

Comment: if you use eclipse, use show annotate - is that what you look for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh... my favourite svn tool `svn blame`.

When you use TortoiseSVN, right click the file, select **TortoiseSVN**, select **Blame...**

Set your `from` and `to` revisions to narrow it down if you know approximate timeframe, else use `1` and `HEAD`

Do **not** select *Use text viewer to view blames*

While viewing the file with TortoiseBlame, hover over the revision column of the line you are interested in, and it will show the commit message text (with the revision number and author already shown

Right click on the revision column of the line you are interested in, and select **Blame previous revision**. Review the commit message and the author again. Repeat as much as needed to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Not as fancy and automatic as I had hoped, but seems to work alright. Thanks!